# Good books for Support department management

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have a small support department that has recently started using MS Dynamics CRM. As a developer, I occasional check active cases to see what problems are occurring in our software so it may be addressed. However, I usually find the cases emails, notes, questions asked, resolutions etc are not to my satisfaction.
Does anyone have any good book references I can pass to the support manager to help him improve the department, his skills in management and how to better utilise CRM?

Cheers

Comment: Are you interested in the technical elements of building solutions for the platform or in how to use it? The content seems to me to be about processes that the support department is using, while the responses provided are books on building solutions using out of the box configuration and custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the CRM references guys, we have got a few and our support manager is busy reading up.

Comment: Mike - you are correct, I was hoping for more business process books as well as ones that can help the support guys grow in their careers. CRM is obviously a big part of the support department, but it doesn't help if our guys are not asking the right questions etc.

Answer (score 5):

I'm biased because I work with the writers, but even after four years of working with CRM, I still reference the Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM on occasion. For people trying to just get started with CRM (and maybe of more benefit to someone working in support) both the Step by Step and Working with Dynamics CRM books were written by colleagues of mine with years of CRM experience.

- [Programming Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625948)
- [Working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623783)
- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Step By Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562576X)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend:
[Dynamics CRM 4.0 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329700)